# Fix com.day.cq.commons,version=[5.7,6) can't be resolved in OSGi Bundles in AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

when you working with AEM 6.2 you might have came across below error,

> com.day.cq.commons,version=[5.7,6)-->can't be resolved

This happened in AEM 6.2 Versions

I answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another **Solution** for this issue is :

copy and paste “**cq-commons-5.9.26.jar**”  file in /.m2/repository/com/day/cq/cq-commons/5.9.26

and update pom dependency to below :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
        <artifactId>cq-commons</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.26</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This a hack to fix this issue and might cause other problems.. what happens when the local maven repo is cleared?  If your bundle is complaining about a dependency, and that dependency is an AEM OOTB dependency, you cant just add it to the maven repo.. you have to use the correct dependency from the Adobe repo.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Add below dependency in AEM Core Project pom.xml file

```html
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
          <artifactId>cq-commons</artifactId>
          <version>5.7.4</version>
      </dependency>
```

2. Add Import Package in Core pom.xml

```html
<Import-Package>
         com.day.cq.commons;version="[5.7.0,7.0)",
</Import-Package>
```

build maven and deploy the project in AEM. build should be in active state.

**references:**

The  instruction is a list of packages that are required by the bundle's contained packages. The default for this header is "*", resulting in importing all referred packages.

This header rarely has to be explicitly specified. However, in certain cases when there is an unwanted import, such an import can be removed by using a negation package pattern. The package patterns work in the same way as for , which means they are ordered.

**For example**, if you wanted to import all packages except org.foo.impl you would specify "!org.foo.impl,*"

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, the cq-commons dependency is part of the uber-jar and the uber-jar version should match your AEM version. It looks to me that your uber-jar has a cq-commons dependency version between 5.6-6 and that your AEM installation has a the cq-commons bundle but with higher or lower version than that range. So I’d recommend really figuring out what the differences are in your uber-jar dependency and your AEM installation. While your solution is fine, you are forcing the bundle to expect a certain version range instead of depending on mvn bundle plugin to do that.